# moving files with specific extension to directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to move all files with a `.multianno.txt` from one directory to another.  I thought the command below would work but maybe the `*` is causing problems.  Thank you :).

```
mv /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar/*.multianno.txt /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/annovar/
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar/*.multianno.txt’: No such file or directory
```

directory (`/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar`)

```
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_001_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno.txt
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_002_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno.txt

TSVC_variants_IonXpress_003_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno.txt
```

Comment: That command should work. The error means there are no files that have that extension in the source directory.

Comment: added an edit showing the actual files names in the directory.  Thanks :).

Comment: There's no `.` before `multianno` in the filenames.

Comment: Thank you... late in the day  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filenames end in `_multianno.txt`, not `.multianno.txt`, so use

```
mv /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar/*_multianno.txt /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/annovar/
```